# Null Properties Down Stream in MVC / MVVM

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a Person Model

```
Person
{
    firstName //Required
    lastName //Required
    jobTitle //Optional
}
```

In my database, I have an entry ("John", "Smith", "")

When I retrieve the model, I will set Person.jobTitle to NULL.

Now I want to render this entry in a view as such

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Smith
Job Title: Unknown
```

In the MVVM pipeline, where should this transition from NULL to Unknown be made?

Should it:

1) Propagate all the way down to the view, where potentially another programmer would need to know to do the null check?

2) Be transformed when creating the view model, where the view model would have a property along the lines of jobTitleDisplayValue.

3) Should there be two properties in the view model, along the lines of doesJobTitleExist and jobTitle.  This way another programmer would know that jobTitle can be null.

4) Should the property in the model itself not be NULL?

5)...

Comment: did you try a solution? Did it work? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this specific example you would ideally just use data annotations to deal with this rather than generating extra properties. See linked article on how you can alter display text for null values:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.nulldisplaytext(v=vs.110).aspx

But outside this specific example I think I get what you are asking and it is going to be one of those questions which the answer will properly differ from dev to dev. Personally, I am a fan of transforming the data as I'm loading it into my view model because that is basically the whole purpose of it (imo) to model data for the view. However it does force you to write logic for when you are packing and unpacking the data to the model for updates so data binding becomes more of a chore. I prefer the control of doing it that way though. I am sure that someone with a 300k reputation on here will most likely tell me that I'm completely misguided though.

Comment: Agreed..but I don't have the requisite 300K either ;-)  Seems like the viewmodel is there to *unburden the view*...do things like get the localizations taken care of and make the controls unaware of data artifacts like null.

Answer (score 1):

Let's recape the purpose of an MVVM architecture:

- the *View* is how you *display* your data
- the *ViewModel* is where you put the *business logic* and the *information* (through the *Model*), without knowing anything of the *View*.

Thus, the `null` is the thing that matters from a *ViewModel* point of view: it brings an important *information* about which is the real, effective `JobTitle`: `null`.

The *View* could represent the `JobTitle` just as it wants: as `Unknown` or `Not asked` or `Not available`... but the *business logic* will remain the same: a `null` `JobTitle`.

Clarified this, you have at least 2 options:

1) Use the [TargetNullValue property of the Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue)
In this case you'd write:

```
Text="{Binding JobTitle, TargetNullValue=Unknown}"
```

2) Use a [Converter](https://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html), and in the `Convert` method write:

```
return value ?? "Unknown";
```

I'd use the first option, it's simpler.

Comment: for the second option, would `return job ?? "Unknown";` not sufice?